# How to handle where clause in GraphQL Schema

Tags: graphql

I am new to GraphQL and creating a API Server using Flask and GraphQL,
Facing some issues while handling the "where" clause in GraphQL Request.

The basic Request and Response is working fine . please find a short snippet of the Schema I have designed

```graphql
type data {
    edges:[data_edges]
}

type QueryCustom {
    data: data
}

type Query {
    query: QueryCustom
}
```

Below mentioned basic request (Without the where clause) is working fine with this schema

```graphql
query { 
    query {
        data {
            edges { .... }
```

But Getting an error when I am executing the Request with the where clause

```graphql
query dataClosingSoon($month: Long) {
 query{
    data(where: { LastModifiedDate: { CALENDAR_MONTH: { value: { eq: $month } } } } ) {
            edges { ....... }
```

Following is the response I get:

```json
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "locations": [
                {
                    "column": 40,
                    "line": 1
                }
            ],
            "message": "Unknown type 'Long'."
        },
        {
            "locations": [
                {
                    "column": 9,
                    "line": 5
                }
            ],
            "message": "Unknown argument 'where' on field 'QueryCustom.data'."
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to understand how to handle the where condition.

Answer (score 2):

GraphQL is not SQL. You cannot use SQL clauses such as `WHERE`, `LIKE`, etc. in a GraphQL query.

You need to look at the schema to check how can you filter your query. These filters are pre-defined in the schema. You cannot create custom filters (at least in a basic sense) for a GraphQL query.

**Edit:**

If you want to use the query you are trying to send, your schema should look like something this:

```
type data {
    edges:[data_edges]
}

type Query {
    data(where: Filter!): data
}

input type Filter {
    lastModifiedDate: // the type of this field
    // Rest of the input fields
}
```

Note that your first query and the second query are totally different. Your second query is clearly wrong due to two reasons:

1. The `Query` type does not have a field called `data`. It only has one field called `query`. (I wouldn't add a field named `query` under the `Query` type though).
2. Your `data` field does not have any inputs. But your document (the GraphQL request) clearly does.

Comment: I am sorry but I have to disagree with you on this , Basically I am trying to create a salesforce simulator , and this request is working perfectly fine when I am sending it on the real END POINT (Sales Force)

Comment: Yes, it would work, if the salesfore GraphQL schema allows it. The schema you posted here does now allow `where` as an input parameter.

Comment: Thanks @ThisaruG for your response , I updated the first and second REQ again , it was a typo mistake , I tried changing the schema as you suggested.

    `input type Filter {
    lastModifiedDate: String!
    }

    type QueryCustom{
        data(where: Filter!):data

    }`

***But the same issue is observed***

Comment: Just updating the schema won't fix your issue. In the answer, I just showed you how the schema should be. You have to define the `Filter` type correctly, and handle that in your code.